# How to determine the notion of parallel transport within the conformal or projective and general connections?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, connections

I'd like to know how the parallel transportation behaves in non-Levi-Civita connections and how does one realize it formally.

I know that parallel transportation  along some piece-smooth curve is defined through moving by geodesics: say, in case of conformal connection, one transports a vector along a short geodesic close to a piece of the given curve preserving the **angle** at each moment of moving, so, for example moving by a horizontal line in the flat realization of the Lobachevsky plane (where geodesics are semicircles and vertical lines) one gets that a vector rotates uniformly.

But how does one understand the parallel transport in general (of a general connection given on a principal bundle)? So, are there any axioms of the parallel transport except being an isomorphism between model spaces in close points on a smooth manifold and "additivity: moving along one piece of a curve and then the second" and "inverse: going in both sides" axioms?

Comment: These matters are discussed in M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics* chapter 10 and in a pedagogical paper by [Bernstein & Phillips](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250802309_Fiber_Bundles_and_Quantum_Theory). See also this [PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773269/how-is-the-geometry-of-the-magnetic-vector-potential-determined-in-the-original/773444#773444). Regarding parallel transport on principal bundles you may want to look up [Wilson loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_loop) as well.